# JVM method invocation internals when simultaneous invocation

Tags: java, methods, jvm

The title was hard to formulate, so if someone could make it more concise I would be greatful.

I know how method invocation works in Java. Basically the JVM holds a lookup table where to find a specific method and then invokes it.

Assume we have for example a list of instances from type MyClass and we process these with a parallel stream by calling i.E. toString() on every instance. There will be multiple threads calling toString() at the very same moment. All point to the same toString() in the method stack.

So my question is: Is there some internal synchronization going on inside the JVM to handle this? Or does every object have its own method inlined?

I could not find any detailed information on this. Oracle Docs are too high level for this. Pointers would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There's no reason multiple threads can't execute the same code at the same time. The code is static (loaded once when the class is loaded), so it doesn't require any synchronization.

Comment: Synchronization to handle what? What 'method stack'? What are you talking about?

Comment: This sounds like a misunderstanding of computer engineering basics to me. I suggest you learn how assembly or C code gets executed, then how multi-threading works in that context. In the end a JVM just uses the same concepts with a lot of embellishments.

Comment: Though all object point to the same toString(), they have separate member variable values.

Comment: @the8472 That was never my strong suit in my studies. Perhaps it is too long ago (about 7 years I learned that). Do you have any link to the multithreading explanation you are writing about?

Comment: @JoeDirect Do you have an explanation for why you are expecting a multithreading problem to occur?

Comment: @EJP No expectation of error here. Just want to know how this is accomplished.

Comment: How what is accomplished? What problem are you trying to solve? What *concurrency* problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know how method invocation works in Java. Basically the JVM holds a lookup table where to find a specific method and then invokes it.

Correct.

> Assume we have for example a list of instances from type MyClass and we process these with a parallel stream by calling i.E. toString() on every instance. There will be multiple threads calling toString() at the very same moment. All point to the same toString() in the method stack.

Correct.

> So my question is: Is there some internal synchronization going on inside the JVM to handle this?

No. Why? The code is read-only: it doesn't require sequentialized access.

> Or does every object have its own method inlined?

No. Why would it need that?

Comment: I don't know why but **read-only** finally let it click. The byte code is a series of commands which then gets translated to machine code which oversimplified runs in registers. Because the data they work on lies in different registers, no synchronization problem arises.

Comment: @JoeDred I have no idea what you mean by 'runs in registers', but you should upvote and/or accept any answer you find useful.

Comment: Accepted your answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Data is synchronized, not the code (methods).

Each thread has its own [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) where local variables and return addresses of the invoked methods chain are stored. When a program encounters a method invocation, the address of the return point (the instruction to execute when the method call completes) is stored on the thread stack and the program flow jumps to the new method (executes instructions of that method).

There can be many threads that execute the same code (the same set of instructions that are located somewhere in the memory), but each thread has its own stack.

Comment: Hm, Oracle states otherwise. 
> The Java Virtual Machine has a method area that is shared among all Java Virtual Machine threads.
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.4. Perhaps I lack the understanding or it is poorly explained.

Comment: @JoeDred 'States otherwise' how? The method area isn't the same thing as a thread stack. What are you talking about?

Comment: @EJP My understanding is that there exist a method lookup table to look up the methods byte code. So when you invoke a method the lookup table is asked where to find that method and then executes it. Am I wrong on that one?

Comment: No, but where is the concurrency problem in that? And where is the contradiction with @DraganBozanovic's answer? Where is the 'otherwise'?

Answer (score 0):

Getting more techincal but ..

> Basically the JVM holds a lookup table where to find a specific method and then invokes it.

It does but it can inline multiple implementations of a method by-passing the need to use such a look up table.

> There will be multiple threads calling toString() at the very same moment. All point to the same toString() in the method stack.

While code is notionally read-only, it in fact is compiled and recompiled in stages, possibly decompiled as well. Each time this happens the code has actually changed. It does the same thing, but a different way.  What is does is swap the reference to code while it is running and it can mean that different threads could be running different versions of the same method for a breif period of time.

> So my question is: Is there some internal synchronization going on inside the JVM to handle this?

It doesn't use a JVM visible lock, and I suspect it doesn't use  mutex style lock at all, instead it use a thread safe operation to swap the method which should be called.

> Or does every object have its own method inlined?

Objects have data, not methods.  Object have a reference to a class which has references to methods.  These references can change over the life of the application.